# Simple Red5 X Flash AS3 Comunication Example (Send Strings)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, red5

I searched the web but can't find a simple example for sending strings to a server red5 RTMP, using an as3 (flash ide-compiled).

where can I find a tutorial about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is fairly broad, but I can direct you to an old blog post of mine that gives examples of how to send AS3 Vectors. This may help you with how to perform communication with the server. http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/08/red5-vector-support/

Answer (score 0):

You can send Strings or any Custom Objects by following this tutorial : [Custom Object](http://gregoire.org/2008/09/12/using-custom-objects-in-amf3-with-red5/)

Communication from as3 client to red5 server can be done by using the call method of netconnection as described in [Application handlers](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/red5/migration-guide/) part.

On Server side

```
public void myFunc(String myString) {
//do work
}
```

On Client side

```
nc.call("myFunc", null, "Hello World");
```